# C Set implementation using linked lists memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Valgrind insists that this function has a memory leak but I am not able to find it. This is part of a set implementation using linked lists in c.

```
int set_add(set * s,int e[2]){
        if(set_empty(*s)) {
                element * new=malloc(sizeof (element));
                new->coord[0]=e[0];
                new->coord[1]=e[1];
                new->next =NULL;
                s->head=new;
                return 1;
        }
        element * current=s->head;
        while(current != NULL) {
                if(coord_equal(current->coord,e)) {
                        return 0;
                }
                if(current->next ==NULL){
                  break;
                }
                current=current->next;
        }
        element * new=malloc(sizeof (element));
        new->coord[0]=e[0];
        new->coord[1]=e[1];
        new->next = NULL;
        current->next=new;
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: `while(current != NULL)`...`current->next=new;`. Looks like `current` is NULL on that last line.

Comment: no it breaks when current->next is null therefore current isn't null, it was coded that way so that set with only one element get checked too

Answer (score -1):

I think the right thing to do is verify after each malloc if indeed it was allocated and if not, you should free that memory zone and exit the function.

Something like this:

```
value = malloc();
if (value){
//value was allocated correctly
//do the things you want with it
free(value);
}
else{
return 0; //exit your function
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would a `free` be needed if the `malloc` failed? Makes no sense.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant to say that after you are done with your value, you should free it, like at the end of if, I'm editing it now, thanks.

Comment: That does not help the OP. The point of the function it to allocate a new element for later use. So it's not meant to have a `free` in that piece of code.

Comment: good point kaylum, we use a different function to free the set